# How can I publish to Google Pub/Sub from frontend mobile clients?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it considered good practice to have my mobile clients publish messages directly to Pub/Sub?

I am looking to publish topics about user views, taps, and overall activity information directly into Pub/Sub. The volume of data inflow is quite large, so I don't want to use Cloud Functions (will overkill on no. of invocations) or Cloud Endpoints (will unnecessarily flood my logs with pretty granular activity data).

But I have been searching Google Cloud's documentation, and could not find any way to securely publish messages from frontend (web, mobile) clients. I can solve this by giving a simple service account key (that only has publishing roles), but that seems bad practice to embed account key `json` files into the client?

The answer to a similar question: [Is it good practice to have a React Native app Publish directly to a Google Pub/Sub topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352630/is-it-good-practice-to-have-a-react-native-app-publish-directly-to-a-google-pub?rq=1) suggested putting Pub/Sub behind Cloud Functions, which I feel would incur a lot of costs for the data I am piping through.

Comment: If you are concerned about the cost of Cloud Functions have you reviewed the data costs? You might be focusing on the wrong problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution paper is a fairly comprehensive answer to your question. There are others of course.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setting-up-a-pubsub-proxy-for-mobile-clients-on-gke

Comment: This is a well-developed solution guide. But that implies that Google never intended you to have clients publish messages directly to Pub/Sub, rather you need a proxy in the middle?